# Different response on different computers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, openssl

I'm running the following code on two different computers:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.zalando.co.uk:443/api/graphql/"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"}
json=[{"id": "e7f9dfd05f6b992d05ec8d79803ce6a6bcfb0a10972d4d9731c6b94f6ec75033", "variables": {"addToCartInput": {"clientMutationId": "addToCartMutation", "productId": "NI111A04M-A110009000"}}}]
print(requests.post(url, headers = headers, json= json).json())
```

One computer is a Macbook Pro *(running macOS Catalina)* and the second computer is an iMac (running macOS Big Sur). With this in mind, both computers are running the same version of python (3.7.9), have the same version of OpenSSL version (1.1.1g) and have the same version of python requests installed (2.25.1).

That said when I run the code, I get the following output on my Macbook:

```
[{'data': {'addToCart': {'__typename': 'AddToCartPayload'}}}]
```

and this on my iMac:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;zalando&#46;co&#46;uk&#47;api&#47;graphql&#47;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#82;&#85;18&#46;8130f9c1&#46;1608567608&#46;2190f96c
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I'm extremely puzzled about why it is happening and was wondering if anyone has a solution to this problem and how I could get the response I'm getting on my Macbook on my iMac. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure at all if it could matter, but maybe you are logged in on one of the computers by default and not on the other?

Comment: @Thymen Hey Thymen, Thank you very much for your comment. Unfortunately no (I don't even have an account on the website), any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it is a website issue, but could you have admin privilege's on one computer and not on the other?

Comment: Not really, the last things I could think are difference in browser versions, have you verified that the headers are the same on both computer? But that is a really long shot.

Comment: @itprorh66 Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately no (I don't have any admin privileges). Have you tried running the code? what message to you get?

Comment: @Thymen I python requests so the browser version doesn't really matter. What concerns the code. I saved it and ran it on an other computer (It's identical).

Comment: No, I don't have a Mac to run on.

Comment: When I attempt to access the web page i get the following error message "Sorry, we’re a little lost Looks like that page has been moved, deleted or disappeared in the wash. Tell us who you’re shopping for and we’ll get you back on track."